# Spinner onItemSelected does not work

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

```
private Spinner spinnerMonth;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater
        , @Nullable ViewGroup container
        , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinnerMonth, container, false);
     // Month
    spinnerMonth = (Spinner) _view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth);
    spinnerMonth.setAdapter(monthAdapter);
    spinnerMonth.setSelection(_selectedMonth - 1);
    return _view;
}

private void saveData() {
    spinnerMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("month",i);        
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}
```

My codes above. If I determine a global Spinner, onItemSelected does not work. If I determine a local Spinner, it is work. Why this happen? I need a global Spinner.

Comment: write spinner onitemclicklistner inside onActivity created method

Comment: When saveData() will executed ?

Comment: bingo main problem is `private void saveData()` put this code in onCreateView ... listner should be setup on creating view on in method.. if you want method then call this method inside the onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater
        , @Nullable ViewGroup container
        , @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinnerMonth, container, false);
     // Month
    spinnerMonth = (Spinner) _view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth);
    spinnerMonth.setAdapter(monthAdapter);
    spinnerMonth.setSelection(_selectedMonth - 1);
    spinnerMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.d("month",i);        
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
    return _view;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working but I need setOnItemSelectedListener triggered when on click a save button. That's why it does not work.

Comment: @mute_person still the spinner is global.. ok do one thing just call Savedata() in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

To define the selection event handler for a spinner, implement the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener interface and the corresponding onItemSelected() callback method.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
        {

        }           
    });
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html